# No I2C Devices Found in atmega644 with i2cLCD

Tags: arduino, i2c

I am beginner I wanted to determine the I2C address I connect my arduino644 to I2C LCD like the pin below

```
I2C LCD(BLUE)        |       ATMEGA644

GND                  |       GND

5V                   |       5V

SDA                  |       A4

SCL                  |       A5
```

I used the I2C Scanner Code in example list but it gives me output NO I2C DEVICE
any idea thank you

Answer (score 0):

Usually I2C needs a pull-up resistor to work properly. Most of the times, you need to set this in your breadboard or PCB.

Do you have an multimeter to check the voltage on both SDA and SCL on idle? If yes, do so.
You also can check the LCD datasheet to check if they already have the pull-up resistors. And i can say that the arduino doesn't.